# Differences in the names of Windows Features .Net Framework

Tags: c#, cmd

I have to turn on all parts of windows features in `.Net Framework 3.5` and `4.7.1`/`4.7.2`/`4.8` in my `wix` installer by a custom action in C#.

I try do it by cmd:

```
DISM / online / enable-feature / featurename: Name
```

I also tried the power shell command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Type feature name" -all
```

But the problem is when the windows features for `.Net Framework` are enabled, the power shell command does not turn on the rest.

That's why I stayed with cmd. 
And the problem is that in my script I need to know all the `Part Names` of these windows features to check if they are enabled or disabled.
I checked it by myself which changes are enable when `.Net Framework 3.5` and `4.8` are enabled on Windows 10.
Also I checked it for `3.5` and `4.7.2` on `Windows Server 2012`. And there were differences. 
Now I don't know if it's through the system or through the `.Net Framework` versions.

```
    private static void AddFeatureNet48()
    {
        featureToEnable.Add(0, "NetFx3");
        featureToEnable.Add(1, "NetFx4-AdvSrvs");
        featureToEnable.Add(2, "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(3, "WCF-Services45");
        featureToEnable.Add(4, "WCF-TCP-PortSharing45");
        featureToEnable.Add(5, "WCF-Pipe-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(6, "WCF-TCP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(7, "WCF-MSMQ-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(8, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
        featureToEnable.Add(9, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45");
        featureToEnable.Add(10, "WAS-NetFxEnvironment");
        featureToEnable.Add(11, "IIS-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(12, "IIS-ManagementService");
        featureToEnable.Add(13, "IIS-ASPNET");
        featureToEnable.Add(14, "WCF-HTTP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(15, "WCF-HTTP-Activation");
        featureToEnable.Add(16, "WCF-NonHTTP-Activation");
    }
    private static void AddFeatureNet472()
    {
        featureToEnable.Add(0, "NetFx3");
        featureToEnable.Add(1, "NetFx3ServerFeatures");
        featureToEnable.Add(2, "NetFx4");
        featureToEnable.Add(3, "NetFx4ServerFeatures");
        featureToEnable.Add(4, "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(5, "WCF-TCP-PortSharing45");
        featureToEnable.Add(6, "WCF-Pipe-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(7, "WCF-MSMQ-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(8, "WCF-TCP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(9, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
        featureToEnable.Add(10, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45");
        featureToEnable.Add(11, "WAS-NetFxEnvironment");
        featureToEnable.Add(12, "IIS-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(13, "IIS-ManagementService");
        featureToEnable.Add(14, "WCF-HTTP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(15, "WCF-HTTP-Activation");
        featureToEnable.Add(16, "WCF-NonHTTP-Activation");
    }
```

It also looks different:

[image]

I am not able to check how it looks on Windows Server 2016.
Will it not be otherwise?

Could anyone tell me why does this difference arise? Or will I find somewhere a list of Windows features for these versions.

In my script, I checked if Windows features are enabled and compared them with the list. 
I remove from list those that are included and the rest which where in the correct order I turned them on.

Comment: What sort of application installation relies upon *every subcomponent* of both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.x? It seems unlikely, especially as you're unsure on the list of features. You ought to (if you're going to do this at all rather than just list pre-requisites for installation) just turn on the features your application actually depends upon.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Extended application used IIS, Http, netpipe, Services. Maybe it really doesn't use something, I can't say it because I only do the installer for it, and I didn't work on it, but I have such a task and I have to turn everything on. Even if I had to include a part, the same problem will occur - name differences.

Comment: You can parse the output of "get-windowsoptionalfeature -online" from elevated PowerShell, then filter them by those containing the word netfx, iis and wcf

Comment: @Martheen but with iis are more windows features names. but I think something in this direction, thanks